# Join Algorithms and Buffer Pool correlation in Database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, algorithm, join

I'm trying to understand what a buffer pool is, and how to know what a determined **Join Algorithm** needs to have in terms of Buffer Space in order to work, and in order to be more efficient.

To give you more an idea of what i don't understand I show an image below that lists the properties I would like to know given a Join Algorithm.

NOTE: I'm not interested in the solution (as you can see I already have them). What I'm interested in, is how do I need to think about these algorithms in terms of necessary buffer size and so on.

I tried already to find the way of thinking about this but I didn't manage to understand much, and online it's pretty hard to find some good articles explaining this subject.

Can someone give me some help?

---

[image: Example]